# dispaly runtime errors of gcc to a file?

Tags: php, ubuntu, gcc

I am trying to display runtime errors to a file.
I have compiled it using gcc iam able to cope up with compile time errors how do i display runtime errors to a file ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that, the one I use usually is:

```
script -c "compile commands here" fileName.script
```

The result is saved in `fileName.script` file.

Comment: can you elaborate pls like using for compilation shell_exec("gcc filename.c) and execution shell_exec("./a.out ") how to i display runtime errors caused by filename